# Divide columns in array without loops

Tags: arrays, numpy, division

For example:

Input:

```
a = array([[1, 2], [4, 10], [4, 6]]])
```

Output:

```
b = array([[4, 5], [1, 0.6]])
```

`a` can have more than three rows.

Comment: I would appreciate any feedback if you found it useful or need further details.

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help

Comment: Glab I could help, please consider accepting the answer as well (green check mark on the left!).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [`np.roll`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html), by dividing `a` by `a`-*shifted*:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2], [4,10], [4,6]])
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 4,  6]])

>>> shifted_a = np.roll(a, shift=1, axis=0)
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 4, 10]])

>>> shifted_a / a
array([[0.25      , 0.33333333],
       [4.        , 5.        ],
       [1.        , 0.6       ]])
```

Then discard the first rows:

```
>>> (shifted_a / a)[1:]
array([[4. , 5. ],
       [1. , 0.6]])
```